# Regular Expression to validate a string containing '$' as end character

Tags: c#, regex

In c#, I have to validate a string which contains "$" at the end using RegEx.

For example: etc$, abcd$ etc.

Currently, i am using `^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+$`  to validate a string containing alphanumerics and _ and -

Comment: Sort of unrelated, but what about the alphanumerics åäö 世襲 and such? Usually there is a built-in operator for alphanumerical operators that have a higher chance of matching non-US characters.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `\$` to match a literal `$` character.

Answer (score 1):

In regex, the `$` actually represents the end-of-the line. You should escape it with `\$` to match it:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\$
```

To make it fully-match, from beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`) of the string, you should use:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Try use

```
\$$
```

or

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+\$$
```

where

```
\$ means the '$' symbol
$ means the end of string
```

Answer (score 1):

`$` has a special meaning.It specifies the end of the string(or line in multiline mode)

So,you need to escape `$`like this `\$`

This is the regex you want

```
^[\w-]+\$$

//\w is [a-zA-Z0-9_]
```

Answer (score 0):

One of alternatives is:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9_-]+[$]$ 
                  ↑
                  this is end of line/string
```